# JavaScript Button Login

Tags: javascript, button

So I'm trying to create a JavaScript code for a button that allows me to login to a website that I have created. I have my database that the information will be retrieving the verification from. I just can't seem to get the functionality to the button to do such a thing. So far all I have done was trying to reverse engineer the Facebook code login button but yet all I had on my hands after that was a big mess. I know I'm a bit over my head in this situation. JavaScript isn't my best language. I have a button right now and that's it.

Comment: Could you please tell us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Should we guess what you have so far or do you plan to share the source code with us to enable help?

Comment: And I have a car I just can't seem to get working... (*We need a lot more details*).

Comment: Sorry, I haven't really tried anything. Just the basic, but nothing really to communicate with my server. I really don't know how to tackle the situation. Should have added more clarity in the explanation, and I do apologize for that.

Comment: have you considered using firebase as a server for what you trying to do? you will be able to create a form, have users register, login and redirect them to specific pages they can only view if logged in  - http://www.firebase.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a JavaScript question but a design question.
You are dealing with three levels here. In brief -

1. View - Your html (button), css & JS
2. Controller - Your space for action, validation and logic
3. Data - Your data stored in your DB

You've got the view (partially) and the Data layers figured out; however, you haven't worked on your controller layer.

Your controller layer should consume the data from the view (login details), validate the data, transform (if necessary) and authenticate against the DB.

You can build your controller on the server (Java, nodeJS, etc.) or on the client (JavaScript AJAX).

Hence, I suggest you figure out where do you want your code to live - on your server or in the browser. You should also keep in mind security.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed.